# Reminder added through app not showing alarm time

Tags: ios, swift, reminders

I am in the process of writing an app that allows users to add a reminder with an alarm time.  The reminder is working correctly and the alarm is going off when it should, but when I go into the Reminders app and look at the reminder that was set in my app, the alarm text is not appearing under the reminder name in the `UITableViewCell`.

Here is the Reminders app showing a reminder set through the Reminders app and one set through my app:

[image]

Even though the text is not showing up in the cell, if I edit the reminder, the alarm is set correctly:

[image]

Right now, there's not much to the app - I am just getting started.  Here's the screen that I'm currently using to add the reminder.

[image]

This is the code that is being used to add the reminder and alarm:

```
func createReminder() {

    let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: appDelegate.eventStore!)

    reminder.title = reminderText.text!
    reminder.calendar =
        appDelegate.eventStore!.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
    let date = myDatePicker.date
    let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date)

    reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

    do {
        try appDelegate.eventStore?.save(reminder,
                                         commit: true)
    } catch let error {
        print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your issue. I just used your code to create a reminder and it just created a reminder without the date in the subtitle.

What we need to understand is setting an alarm date != the due date of the reminder. Users can set a due date/timing and add reminders before the due date. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekreminder/1507383-duedatecomponents) for more information.

To add the date you need to set the ***dueDateComponents*** property of the ***EKReminder*** object that you pass to eventStore. Like below,

```
let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: eventStore)
reminder.title = reminderText
reminder.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(10000)
let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date)
reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

let dateComponents = NSDateComponents();
dateComponents.year = 2018
dateComponents.day = 14
dateComponents.hour = 11
dateComponents.month = 1
reminder.dueDateComponents = dateComponents as DateComponents

do{
     try eventStore.save(reminder, commit: true)
} catch let error {
     print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

The screenshot below shows 4 events. 1st and the last were created manually, the second was created from your code without dueDateComponents and the third one was created with dueDateComponents.

[image: The one with the red one was created with dueDateComponents]

Comment: @ScottKilbourn :)